# Algorithm for collecting total events within the last certain time

Tags: algorithm, embedded

I am facing an algorithm problem.

We have a task that runs every 10ms and during the running, an event can happen or not happen. Is there any simple algorithm that allows us to keep track of how many time an event is triggered within the latest, say, 1 second?

The only idea that I have is to implement an array and save all the events. As we are programming embedded systems, there is not enough space...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could store a variable that is reset every second to 0, then increment it with each event that happens.

Comment: @bdares: I think the events are not binaries, they have properties... could be wrong though, the OP should clarify this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As the time window is moving, I cannot reset the counter by this way. We would like to keep track of the total number of events within the latest time interval... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @amit The events are binaries, either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Note that it does not follow that because it is an embedded system there is not enough space.  That is an attribute of your particular embedded system, not embedded systems in general.

Answer (score 2):

an array of 13 bytes for a second worth of events in 10ms steps.

consider it an array of 104 bits marking 0ms to 104ms

if the event occurs mark the bit and increment to the next time, else just increment to next bit/byte.

if you want ... run length encode after each second to offload the event bits into another value.
       or   ... treat it as a circular buffer and keep the count available for query.
       or   both

You could reduce the array size to match the space available.

It is not clear if an event could occur multiple times while your task was running, or if it is always 10ms between events.

Comment: Further... If you increment a counter each time a 0 bit is replaced with a 1 and decrement when a 1 is replaced with a 0, then you can maintain a running count without having to explicitly count the bits - which will be faster and more deterministic.  This avoids any need for the run-length encoding for storing historical data, it is possible to simply copy the counter.

Comment: Good point, I made the assumption you would have to maintain your position in the array on each call.  Your code looks "Ok" ( I lack the mod points to comment on it), but I'd do it a little differently... of course ;). The RLE would be for offloading the information elsewhere for historical reference preserving periodicity and patterns for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 2):

This is more-or-less what Dtyree and Weeble have suggested, but an example implementation may help ( C code for illustration):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define HISTORY_LENGTH 100  // 1 second when called every 10ms

int rollingcount( bool event )
{
    static uint8_t event_history[(HISTORY_LENGTH+7) / 8] ;
    static int next_history_bit = 0 ;
    static int event_count = 0 ;

    // Get history byte index and bit mask
    int history_index = next_history_bit >> 3 ;             // ">> 3" is same as "/ 8" but often faster
    uint8_t history_mask = 1 << (next_history_bit & 0x7) ;  // "& 0x07" is same as "% 8" but often faster

    // Get current bit value
    bool history_bit = (event_history[history_index] & history_mask) != 0 ;

    // If oldest history event is not the same as new event, adjust count
    if( history_bit != event )
    {
        if( event )
        {
            // Increment count for 0->1
            event_count++ ;

            // Replace oldest bit with 1
            event_history[history_index] |= history_mask ;
        }
        else
        {
            // decrement count for 1->0
            event_count-- ;

            // Replace oldest bit with 0
            event_history[history_index] &= ~history_mask ;
        }
    }

    // increment to oldest history bit
    next_history_bit++ ;
    if( next_history_bit >= HISTORY_LENGTH ) // Could use "next_history_bit %= HISTORY_COUNT" here, but may be expensive of some processors
    {
        next_history_bit = 0 ;
    }

    return event_count ;
}
```

For a 100 sample history, it requires 13 bytes plus two integers of statically allocated memory, I have used `int` for generality, but in this case `uint8_t` counters would suffice.  In addition there are three stack variables, and again the use of `int` is not necessary if you need to really optimise memory use.  So in total it is possible to use as little as 15 bytes plus three bytes of stack.  The `event` argument may or may not be passed on the stack, then there is the function call return address, but again that depends on the calling convention of your compiler/processor.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of list/queue etc, but a ringbuffer has probably the best performance.
You need to store 100 counters (1 for each time period of 10 ms during the last second) and a current counter.

**Ringbuffer solution:**
(I used pseudo code).

Create a counter_array of 100 counters (initially filled with 0's).

```
int[100] counter_array;
current_counter = 0
```

During the 10 ms cycle:

```
counter_array[current_counter] = 0;   
current_counter++;
```

For every event:

```
counter_array[current_counter]++
```

To check the number of events during the last s, take the sum of counter_array

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said... a list is too expensive for the project and we have to calculate the length of list every 10ms... which is also a cost of time.

Comment: It was not clear for me if you meant with the list all event info or only the time stamps.

Comment: Neither... We only need to know how many time an event has been triggered during the latest 1 s. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you have 10ms periods, you need to store 100 numbers (one for the number of amount of events during that time slot) .. is that too much?

Comment: I changed the solution using a queue, you also can use a simple array, but you need 100 counters.

Comment: thanks, this is only an example. Actually we are looking at the latest 3 mins which means we have to maintain an array of size 1800. If every element is 1 byte. We will have an array of more than 1 KBytes... And we are running out of the memory...

Comment: The problem description says that "***an** event can happen or not happen*" not "***a number** of events*", so you only need one bit for each 10ms period.  If that is not the case then the question is imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you afford an array of 100 booleans? Perhaps as a bit field? As long as you can afford the space cost, you can track the number of events in constant time:

1. Store:

   1. A counter C, initially 0.
   2. The array of booleans B, of size equal to the number of intervals you want to track, i.e. 100, initially all false.
   3. An index I, initially 0.
2. Each interval:

   1. read the boolean at B[i], and decrement C if it's true.
   2. set the boolean at B[i] to true if the event occurred in this interval, false otherwise.
   3. Increment C if the event occurred in this interval.
3. When I reaches 100, reset it to 0.

That way you at least avoid scanning the whole array every interval.

---

EDIT - Okay, so you want to track events over the last 3 minutes (180s, 18000 intervals). Using the above algorithm and cramming the booleans into a bit-field, that requires total storage:

```
2 byte unsigned integer for C
2 byte unsigned integer for I
2250 byte bit-field for B
```

That's pretty much unavoidable if you require to have a precise count of the number of events in the last 180.0 seconds at all times. I don't think it would be hard to prove that you need all of that information to be able to give an accurate answer at all times. However, if you could live with knowing only the number of events in the last 180 +/- 2 seconds, you could instead reduce your time resolution. Here's a detailed example, expanding on my comment below.

The above algorithm generalizes:

1. Store:

   1. A counter C, initially 0.
   2. The array of counters B, of size equal to the number of intervals you want to track, i.e. 100, initially all 0.
   3. An index I, initially 0.
2. Each interval:

   1. read B[i], and decrement C by that amount.
   2. write the number of events that occurred this interval into B[i].
   3. Increment C by the number of events that occurred this interval.
3. When I reaches the length of B, reset it to 0.

If you switch your interval to 2s, then in that time 0-200 events might occur. So each counter in the array could be a one-byte unsigned integer. You would have 90 such intervals over 3 minutes, so your array would need 90 elements = 90 bytes.

If you switch your interval to 150ms, then in that time 0-15 events might occur. If you are pressed for space, you could cram this into a half-byte unsigned integer. You would have 1200 such intervals over 3 minutes, so your array would need 1200 elements = 600 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is implemented but we cannot afford an array of 1800 booleans (the latest 3 mins) :( I'll see if I can free more space from other part of the code...

Comment: Can you trade off preciseness? For example, instead of doing this every 10ms, you could could do it every 2s: count up the (0-200) events over that period. (That will need perhaps 2 bytes storage, one to count the events and one to count the intervals.) Then use an array of counters with the above algorithm - you'll need 180/2 = 90 counters. Your running count would then be within +/-200 of the true total at any given time, and space requirements would be ~92 bytes.

Comment: @user1201566: You should not change the question in a comment to an answer!  Everyone else will still be answering the original question.  If you want tracking over three minutes rather than one second as originally stated, then you should modify the question accordingly, otherwise we are all wasting out time!  In the end though a "*sliding time window*" requires history, and history requires memory; you can't get something from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following work for you application?

A rolling event counter that increments every event.

In the routine that runs every 10ms, you compare the current event counter value with the event counter value stored the last time the routine ran.

That tells you how many events occurred during the 10ms window.